# How to login with user but still stay admin?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I want to implement feature when operator/admin may login as user. Do something under user's credentials and then return back and continue as operator/admin

I try to mount whole application under `/as_user/:user_id` route. So when request come I adjust session to `:user_id`.

I try [`detour`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Routes::Route#detour)

```
$app->routes->route( '/as_user/:app_user' )->detour( app => $app );
```

But in this case when `GET /as_user/17/packages` request come the application fall into infinite loop

Also I think to append `?U=17` query parameter. But I do not know how and where rewrite code in such way: All link should be rendered with `?U=17` appended.

Please advice how to login with another user but still stay admin.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found the answer:

```
$r->under( '/as_user/:user_id', sub{
    # FIX THE SESSION HERE. Just like:
    # $_[0]->session->{ user_id } =  _[0]->match->stack->[-1]->{ user_id };
    return 1; # Required to not break the dispatch chain
})->route('/')->detour( 'App' );
```

Instead of application instance you should pass application class and Mojolicious will instantiate it itself.

PS. Infinite loop maybe because of cyclic refs. (But Mojolicious check refs [here](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-7.49/lib/Mojolicious/Routes.pm#L101))

**UPD** 
Infinite loop because of [bug](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/issues/1148)